# Trouble running cross platform UITests on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin-studio, xamarin.uitest

I am having a few issues running my Xamarin UItests on iOS side of a shared application. The tests run no problem on Android, but I am getting a 
`System.Exception` when I try to run them on iOS.

> SetUp : System.Exception : This app bundle is not valid for running on
>   a simulator. To fix this issue please ensure that your target device
>   is a simulator.To run against an installed app on a physical device
>   you can useInstalledApp("ie.eoin.myapp")

I try run the tests on the simulator as well as on a real device with the same exception. Below is the start of the stack trace.

```
Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchAppLocal(Xamarin.UITest.Configurati`enter code here`on.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Boolean clearAppData) [0x0008a] in <b034e37336b84a95a2482a0c5f0be621>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient xtcServicesClient, System.Boolean testCloudUseDeviceAgent) [0x0007a] in <b034e37336b84a95a2482a0c5f0be621>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00302] in <b034e37336b84a95a2482a0c5f0be621>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <b034e37336b84a95a2482a0c5f0be621>:0 
  at Shared.UITest.AppInitializer.StartApp () [0x00036] in /Users/eoinahern/Documents/xamarin_projs/HomeApp.Mobile/Shared/Shared.UITests/AppInitializer.cs:23 
  at Shared.UITest.Common.SetUp () [0x00002] in /Users/eoinahern/Documents/xamarin_projs/HomeApp.Mobile/Shared/Shared.UITests/Common.cs:17 
  at Shared.UITests.MapScreensTests.SetUp () [0x00002] in /Users/eoinahern/Documents/xamarin_projs/HomeApp.Mobile/Shared/Shared.UITests/MapScreens/MapScreensTests.cs:16 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

In my `startApp()` method in the `AppInitializer` class, the path is pointing to the correct `.app` file in bin directory.

```
public static IApp StartApp()
        {
            switch (TestEnvironment.Platform)
            {
                case TestPlatform.Local:
#if __IOS__
                    platform = Platform.iOS;
                    return ConfigureApp
                                    .iOS
                                    .AppBundle(GetLocalIOSTestAppPath())                                        .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.Clear) as IApp;
#endif

}
```

I am not sure why the tests wont run. I tried changing to an actual device. Also, the `.app` file has what looks like the symbol from a stop sign as its icon. Not sure what this means. I'll check out what that means next, but for now I am stumped. Any help is appreciated. seriously stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this issue?
just as assumption: maybe you need to use .ipa file instead of .app

Comment: You might be on the right track, but you've got it backwards: "This app bundle is not valid for running on a simulator." An .ipa file is built for a device, and an .app file is built for a simulator, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've solved this already, but for anyone else who finds this question:
iOS is super picky about what the configuration is for real devices vs simulators. [This bit of the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/#initialize-iapp-for-ios-applications) should help you out, but in summary:

for real devices, your app configuration should look like this:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .InstalledApp("your.app.name")
    .StartApp();
```

If you use the Installed App, you do have to, yk, install the app on the device before attempting to run the tests.

for simulator devices, your app configuration should look like this:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .AppBundle("your.app.bundle")
    .StartApp();
```

As of the time I'm writing this, there's also the instructions that `InstalledApp` "configures the installed app to use. Will force a run on physical device.", while `AppBundle` "Configures the app bundle to use. Will force a run on a simulator." These distinctions appear to be unique to iOS; the behavior is different on Android.

There's two other app configuration settings that may be applicable here: `DeviceIdentifier` and `PreferIdeSettings`. You can specify which device to run on with the Device Identifier, but the catch is that the simulators and devices will all have different ids on different machines, so be careful about checking that config in. PreferIdeSettings should allow you to use the Visual Studio for Mac device targeting -- see the test layout, unit test pad, and the test apps. Configured properly, you should see both an ios and android project, with the target showing something like `Virtual Device / my_android_emulator (API 28)` or `Device / Your iPhone`.